# MarketingCloudSDK iOS v5.1.1 with Swift 4.1

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios

Is MarketingCloudSDK iOS v5.1.1 compatible with Swift 4.1? It is available via Cocoapods? Last time I checked **pod 'JB4ASDK'** gives v4.9.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MarketingCloud iOS v5.1.1 is fully compatible with Swift 4.1. The SDK does not use Swift internally and all bridging is provided by Xcode; we make sure to update our annotations to support the most effective bridging.

Additionally, our internal testing applications (unit and "user") are built in Swift to ensure the proper functionality.

Re: Cocoapods: https://cocoapods.org/pods/MarketingCloudSDK

Something is incorrect/delayed with the Cocoapods searching; we confirmed that yesterday the latest version was pushed to the pods repo (5.1.1) and the current page (above) is pointing to our current release.

The dependency name for your podfile is `MarketingCloudSDK`.

Best of luck!